# Updating table where column name is a reserved keyword

Tags: database, sql-update, psql

So for some reason, there's a column in the table I'm trying to update called `key`. I want to update a row in this column so I'm attempting to do:

```
UPDATE my_table SET "key" = 'blah';
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_pkey"`
```

From reading about i assumed the quotation marks would have escaped this keyword, but it doesnt seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error is about duplicate value. You already have some record with value 'blah' in the table.

Comment: Yea I just fixed it. I wasn't specifying the exact row i wanted to update, i'm stupid sorry.